# C# IF ELSE on what local db to use?

Tags: c#, database, connection-string

Is there any way to make an IF statement that checks what local db to use, if one is closed, try the next?

I tried starting something here, but i am fairly new at programming and not exactly sure if i am heading in the right direction.

My Database class:

```
public class Database
    {
        public SqlConnection connection()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                if (connection == null)
                {
                    builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-U5Q45EJ";       // Work PC local db name
                }
                else if (connection == null)
                {
                    builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-UPVVOJP";       // Home PC local db name
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to local database failed..");
                }

                builder.InitialCatalog = "Lagersystem";
                builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
                return new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static SqlConnection openConnection()
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
            conn.Open();

            return conn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just get your pc name, and choose via that

Comment: So the statement checks what my current pc name is and chooses local db on that condition? It can do that??

Comment: Why not use 2 different configuration files, one for work and one for home? The code should just pick the connection string from the configuration file. The configuration file would be different in different environment. This also replicates a real life situation where the same software is configured to different settings in different machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Environment.MachineName` gives you your computer name. You can also use `.` which means local instance

so

```
builder.DataSource = System.Environment.MachineName
```

or

```
builder.DataSource = '.'
```